# Spring Data Redis cache in json throws ClassCastException

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

[this](https://github.com/bilak-poc/redis-cache-demo) is sample project of spring-data-redis + caching. I'd like to store caches in redis in plain json, so I've configured `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` with `objectMapper` provided by spring.

Currently when I run test (the only one in application) I'm getting following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.github.bilakpoc.rediscachedemo.generated.model.ModelImport (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.github.bilakpoc.rediscachedemo.generated.model.ModelImport is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.github.bilakpoc.rediscachedemo.service.ImportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14512ec6.getImportById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
```

Please can anybody share how to properly configure redis to store caches in json?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reproducer. You do not need to configure redis cache from code. Only problem was "generated code was not serializable" send you the fix in https://github.com/bilak-poc/redis-cache-demo/pull/1

For future reference

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>openapi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <apiPackage>${openapi-generator.package}.api</apiPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                        </configOptions>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <invokerPackage>${openapi-generator.package}.handler</invokerPackage>
                        <inputSpec>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <modelPackage>${openapi-generator.package}.model</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

serializableModel should be added to configOptions. And @EnableCaching will be enough.

I left comments in [CacheConfig](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/redis-cache-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/bilakpoc/rediscachedemo/config/CacheConfig.java). Actually found another workaround with `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` then I dig in more and found out the real problem.

Comment: with your config it's only java serializer and not json. so still not able to save caches in redis as json objects.

Comment: https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/redis-cache-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/bilakpoc/rediscachedemo/config/CacheConfig.java  here how it works with json. or looks like it works with json, but I did not check redis side.